# Using secure random to generate a long number

Tags: java, random

I have seeded my secure random object with a long number. Now I want to extract another long number. But there is only a function called `nextBytes(byte[] b)` which gives a random `byte[]`.
Is there any way to get a long number?

```
SecureRandom ranGen1 = new SecureRandom();
   ranGen1.setSeed(1000);
   SecureRandom ranGen2 = new SecureRandom();
   ranGen2.setSeed(1000);
   byte[] b1= new byte[3];
   byte[] b2=new byte[3];
   ranGen1.nextBytes(b1);
   ranGen2.nextBytes(b2);
   int a1=b1[0];
   int a2=b1[1];
   int a3=b1[2];

   int c1=b2[0];
   int c2=b2[1];
   int c3=b2[2];

   System.out.println(a1+", "+a2+", "+a3);//genearated by ranGen1
   System.out.println(c1+", "+c2+", "+c3);//generated by ranGen2

   System.out.println(ranGen1.nextLong());//genearated by ranGen1
```

System.out.println(ranGen2.nextLong());//generated by ranGen2

result:

```
4, -67, 69
4, -67, 69

   -3292989024239613972  //this is using nextLong()
-3292989024239613972
```

The Output for Peter Lawrey's code:(Using secure random)

```
-7580880967916090810 -7580880967916090810
7364820596437092015 7364820596437092015
6152225453014145174 6152225453014145174
6933818190189005053 6933818190189005053
-2602185131584800869 -2602185131584800869
-4964993377763884762 -4964993377763884762
-3544990590938409243 -3544990590938409243
8725474288412822874 8725474288412822874
-8206089057857703584 -8206089057857703584
-7903450126640733697 -7903450126640733697
```

They are exaclty the same. How could you get different numbers?

This is the output that I am getting after using Peter Lawrey's second update(I am using windows operating system and he seems to be using some other operaing system which has created the confusion)

```
SHA1PRNG appears to produce the same values with the same seed
The default PRNG on this system is SHA1PRNG
```

Comment: I have added an answer to your comment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have added my answer to my question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Where are you? I tried your code also. See the output that I got for your code in my question.

Comment: @user1166690: Are you using Android? Androids SecureRandom behaves differently than standard Java.

Comment: @RasmusFaber : No the code pasted above was used in in java. But just out of curiousity why would it behave differently in android.

Comment: @user1139023, see my comment down below. It doesn't itself have a PRNG implementation, it uses what's available. From the documentation: This constructor traverses the list of registered security Providers, starting with the most preferred Provider. [..] If none of the Providers support a RNG algorithm, then an **implementation-specific default** is returned."

Comment: @user1166690 On my system there is two algorithms.  The default is not entirely based on the seed.  This is another which is based on the seed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The default in my system is SHA1PRNG. Which is based on the seed.

Comment: It could be worth specifying this algorithm if you need it instead of taking the default.

Comment: **Moderator Note** *Please keep comments constructive and on topic.*

Comment: @RasmusFaber: You are right on seeding the secure random with the same number, different numbersequences are generated in java and android, even though both are using "sha1prng".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Revised again, this is the correct answer! (and I should follow my own advice and read the documentation more carefully)*

Is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) what you're using? If so, it extends Random so it has an inherited nextLong() method. As it overrides next() all the typical Random methods will be using the SecureRandom PRNG method.

(see in the comments why my second answer is incorrect.. or rather unnecessary)

<strike>I would suggest creating a long by just composing it out of the next 8 bytes or of two ints (returned by next). There's no problem with doing that and I can't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to touch all the long values (think that either of the two 32-bit halves can have values from 0 to 2^32, with equal probability) or why one would be more probable than another (which would mean it's not pseudo-random).</strike>

I do not completely understand why the Random documentation indicates that limitation for nextLong(), but I believe it is a limitation of the linear algorithm that it uses (I think linear algorithms have a much shorter cycle - i.e. when they start repeating numbers - than modern PRNGs). I think that's worth exploring on crypto stack exchange for curiosity.

Comment: Random has a seed value of only 48 bits. How will it be able to generate arandom number of 128 bits(Which is the size of secure random)?

Comment: The two things are not related in the way you seem to think they are. A pseudo-random number generator can produce an output of various sizes which are not directly related to the size of the seed. It all depends on the algorithm. What your seed does is just add entropy to the system. The larger the range of values for your seed, the more entropy you may be able to get, but that doesn't affect how large an output you can produce. Stream ciphers are a good example of having pseudo-random output that is considerably larger than the seed.

Comment: To the down-voters: could you please explain what you think is wrong with my answer or offer an alternative solution?

Comment: Refer to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong%28%29

Comment: Excellent, now I understand the problem! :) I would then suggest that the best way to create a long value and still take full advantage of the SecureRandom properties is to do it manually, using a method similar to what the documentation indicates for nextLong() in Random. The limitation that the documentation specifies regarding the seed size is for that type of algorithm, which is obsolete and not really secure anymore (see, for example: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator). Will update answer.

Comment: @AlexFlorescu: this manual random long generation would be exactly what SecureRandom already does. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#next%28int%29. SecureRandom is named SecureRandom for good reasons. If its methods could not be used securely, it wouldn't be secure anymore.

Comment: You are absolutely correct :) I saw your comment to your answer a minute ago and I missed that in the documentation. Will update the answer again :)

Answer (score 4):

SecureRandom extends Random, and Random has a `nextLong()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong%28%29

Comment: :Random has a seed value of only 48 bits. How will it be able to generate arandom number of 128 bits(Which is the size of secure random)?

Comment: @user1139023 You can just look at the implementation. But it's really simple: Concatenate several sequence points together to get a longer number. For reference this is the actual code for `nextLong()`: `return ((long)(next(32)) << 32) + next(32);`

Comment: @Voo :Because class Random uses a seed with only 48 bits, this algorithm will not return all possible long values. Refer to this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong%28%29

Comment: @downvoters: I don't see why my answer deserves a downvote. A SecureRandom generates as many bytes as you want, and the seed is only used to initialize it. SecureRandom has a nextLong() method, and it returns a random long value. I don't see why it couldn't be used.

Comment: @user1139023 Yeah.. quite obviously the longest possible sequence of a 48bit seed is 2^48. So we don't generate *all* possible numbers >48bits, but that doesn't mean we can't generate 64bit or 128bit numbers at all. That's a difference.

Comment: @Voo: You are right we can generate 64 bit numbers, but we will not be able to make full use of the 128 bit range.

Comment: @JBNizet: The link you provided itself says that "Because class Random uses a seed with only 48 bits, this algorithm will not return all possible long values." But I want to utilize my range to the full extent.

Comment: Except the seed and the RNG engine is the one of SecureRandom if you use a SecureRandom. Come on: the name is SecureRandom, and it has a nextLong() value. If it weren't usable and was insecure, do you really think the method would be there? Or at least don't you think there would be a big red warning in the javadoc? Sun's engineers are smarter than that.

Comment: @JBNizet : Are you saying the full range of 128 bits will be used . And I am not saying that sun engineers are not smart or something. I just wanted a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#next%28int%29: *Generates an integer containing the user-specified number of pseudo-random bits (right justified, with leading zeros). This method overrides a java.util.Random method, and serves to provide a source of random bits to all of the methods inherited from that class (for example, nextInt, nextLong, and nextFloat).*

Answer (score 2):

```
BigInteger randomNumber = new BigInteger(numBits, random);
```

Comment: Haven't come across this one before. This is a great option for generating large numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note: With Random, a given seed will always produce the same results. With SecureRandom it will not. The seed just adds to the randomness.

> Have you ever user secure random? The whole point of seed is to produce the same sequesnce of numbers. This is also the case with secure random. Two secure random numbers seeded with the same value produce same sequence of random numbers.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    testRNG("NativePRNG");
    testRNG("SHA1PRNG");
    System.out.println("The default PRNG on this system is " + new SecureRandom().getAlgorithm());
}

private static void testRNG(String prng) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    SecureRandom sr1 = SecureRandom.getInstance(prng, "SUN");
    SecureRandom sr2 = SecureRandom.getInstance(prng, "SUN");
    sr1.setSeed(1);
    sr2.setSeed(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (sr1.nextLong() != sr2.nextLong()) {
            System.out.println(prng + " does not produce the same values with the same seed");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prng + " appears to produce the same values with the same seed");
}
```

prints

```
NativePRNG does not produce the same values with the same seed
SHA1PRNG appears to produce the same values with the same seed
The default PRNG on this system is NativePRNG
```

> go and try it first

Good advice, but just trying it doesn't always give you the whole answer in this case.

Comment: @Peter lawrey: You will not get the same result. I tried your exact same code and have printed the output in my question. Go and see it.

Comment: I have also executed Peter's code and I am getting the type of output he suggests; same seed, different output. So before we start aggressively pointing fingers, perhaps you all need to take a step back and think about what we may be missing. Is there a version difference or something like that?

Comment: I think I figured it out (this article helped: http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/) It seems that SecureRandom will use different PRNGs depending on the implementation which is why I am guessing we are seeing different results. I was able to replicate the problem some of you are seeing (with same output for different instances with the same seed), if I forced SecureRandom to use the PRNG that is default on Windows. If I instantiate it normally (on a Mac), I see different outputs. So if you're running it on windows... there you go.

Comment: @AlexFlorescu :your link was helpul.

Comment: @user1139023 I have updated the code, I assume you have a different default algorithm on your system.